# Get the current Joomla URL

Tags: url

The following code works in Joomla 1.6, but it throws up a Strict Standards error in 3.x:

*Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference*

```
    //Get the full URL for sharing purposes
    $uri = & JFactory::getURI();
    $absolute_url = $uri->toString();

    <?php echo $absolute_url; ?>
```

How can I get the code to work without the error in Joomla 3.x?

Comment: Btw. it doesn't depend on Joomla version but by PHP version. Assigning variables by reference is deprecated in PHP

Comment: Just a note to anyone who seeks an answer for this, to get the **FULL** URL, **do not** use `JUri::current()` as it won't return any query parameters. Simply use what is described in the accepted answer below: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/4295/168

Comment: Best to see api doc https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Uri.Uri.html

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The answer to the main question is:
JFactory::getUri() is deprecated, use JUri directly like this:

```
<?php 
$uri = JUri::getInstance(); 
echo $uri->toString();

// or simpler:

echo JUri::getInstance();
?>
```

The *Strict Standards* error is because of the `&` before `JFactory::getURI();`. You can find more information about that below.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Delete the **&**

```
//Get the full URL for sharing purposes
$uri = JFactory::getURI();
$absolute_url = $uri->toString();

<?php echo $absolute_url; ?>
```

With PHP5 the `new` operator automatically returns a reference, so the '&' is not needed anymore.

From the official PHP manual:

> As of PHP 5, the new operator returns a reference automatically, so assigning the result of new by reference results in an E_DEPRECATED message in PHP 5.3 and later, and an E_STRICT message in earlier versions.

source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Comment: see my answer here->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702983/how-to-get-full-url-of-a-article-by-its-id-in-joomla/35267565#35267565

Answer (score 7):

According to [the Joomla tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/JURI/current), you can get the current URL by this function:

```
JUri::current();
```

Comment: JUri::current() returns the current request URI **without the query or fragment parts**.

For example, if you visit the following URL: 
http://localhost/joomla3/index.php/component/users/?view=remind

JUri::current() would return:
http://localhost/joomla3/index.php/component/users

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:**
`JUri` is now also deprecated. The correct way now is as follows:

```
$uri = \Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri::getInstance();
echo  $uri->toString();
```

(Edited to include an initial backslash - required if there is a current namespace)

Old message that is now also deprecated:

`JFactory::getURI();` is deprecated. The correct method to get the current URL is:

```
$uri = JUri::getInstance();
echo  $uri->toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Relying on the `toString` method to get the current URL is wrong. The `toString` method is not meant for that. The following is a better, cleaner, and future proof approach to retrieve the current URL:

```
$objJURI = JFactory::getURI();
$strQuery = '';
if (!empty($objJURI->getQuery()))
    $strQuery = '?'.$objJURI->getQuery();
$strFragment = '';
if ((!empty($objJURI->getFragment())) && ($objJURI->getFragment() != '#'))
    $strFragment = $objJURI->getFragment();
$currentURL = $objJURI->current().$strQuery.$strFragment;
```

Note that the `getFragment` method should return the part after the number sign, but there seems to be a core bug that prevents it from doing that.

Comment: This is wrong. It will display `index.php&option=com_foo&view=bar`. It should be `?` after `index.php`

Comment: Its absolutely legit to use toString. Its a public method and heavily used by the JUri class itself. Even the method comment says "Returns full uri string.". Using JFactory::getUri(); is deprecated and definitely "more wrong".